# What does an ubuntu preseed file look like for a minimal install?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

What does an ubuntu preseed file look like for a minimal install? My current preseed file installs about 400 packages and is serveral 100MBs.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the answers generated by a base server install.

I've just checked, and a fairly minimal Debian Lenny is ~250 packages. Once real services are installed that quickly baloons on one of my machines to ~550 packages.

Comment: http://u-lite.org/ is remarkably light-weight ubuntu roll. Debian server with apache/cacti/nagios/vpn/zoneminder/lotsofcrap is currently sat at 239 packages installed.